# How do I count the number of blank spaces in a string contained in a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find the number of white / blank spaces contained within the text in the `$measurediv`. Appreciate your help on this.

```
<html>
<div id="welcomeMsgDiv" style="width:210px;">
    <h2 style="font-family:Arial;font-size:17px;font-weight:bold">Welcome,
 First Name Last Name!</h2>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $origdiv = $('div#welcomeMsgDiv');
    $measurediv = $origdiv.clone();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do this. For example (for any type of space):

```
var nbBlankSpaces = $measurediv.text().match(/\s/g).length
```

Comment: didnt see your answer. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You should first define that you are looking for the text.

```
$someVariable = $("selector").text();
```

Then you can use count to get the number of spaces.

```
$charCount = $someVariable.count(" ");
```

Hope this helps out.